# Remove all text before last period in string

Tags: r

I have a string:

`TEMPORAL.LOBE_Oligodendrocytes.SCZ_PGC3_GWAS`

Desired output:

`SCZ_PGC3_GWAS`

There are several variants of this question, I can't seem to find one that specifically removes all text before LAST period.

Comment: `sub('.*[.]', '', s)`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract`:

```r
library(stringr)

s <- "TEMPORAL.LOBE_Oligodendrocytes.SCZ_PGC3_GWAS"

str_extract(s, "(?<=\\.)[^.]*$")

#> [1] "SCZ_PGC3_GWAS"
```

Comment: you have already placed the period in a chaacter class. why escape it again? simply use `[^.]+$`

Comment: Thanks, @onyambu: I did not know that there is no need to escape `.` in this case; I have just learned that from you!

Comment: You do not escape anything once you place it in a character class. the bracket is the charatcer class. eg `[).|]` etc is fine. But outside of the character class you must escape them as they are now metacharacters. Very few metacharacters still has meaning in a character class eg the caret(only when placed at the begining of a character class set), and the hyphen when placed between two characters within a character class.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, @onyambu, for your detailed explanation, which is very helpful to my learning of R!